# Unexpected token & for &#39;

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have define currency_symbol_list as

```
  def currency_symbol_list
    result = []

    Currency.active.each do |currency|
      pre = currency.prefix? ? currency.symbol : ""
      post = currency.prefix? ? "" : currency.symbol

      result << "[#{currency.id}, '#{pre}','#{post}']"
    end

    result.join(', ')
  end
```

This will give result as

```
"[1, '$',''], [2, '','pts'], [3, '&pound;',''], [4, '&euro;',''], [5, 'Rs. ',''], [6, 'CHF ',''], [7, 'C$','']"
```

Upto here I don't have any problem. I getting value as per my wish but when I called currency_symbol_list method with javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var currency_list = [<%= currency_symbol_list %>];
    var accounts_to_currency_list = [<%= accounts_to_currency_symbol_list(@child.pending_accounts) %>];
</script>
```

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` error. And different data is shown

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var currency_list = [[1, &#39;$&#39;,&#39;&#39;], [2, &#39;&#39;,&#39;pts&#39;], [3, &#39;&amp;pound;&#39;,&#39;&#39;], [4, &#39;&amp;euro;&#39;,&#39;&#39;], [5, &#39;Rs. &#39;,&#39;&#39;], [6, &#39;CHF &#39;,&#39;&#39;], [7, &#39;C$&#39;,&#39;&#39;]];
    var accounts_to_currency_list = [[25061, &#39;$&#39;,&#39;&#39;, 1], [25062, &#39;&#39;,&#39;pts&#39;, 2]];
</script>
```

Before pre variable and after post varible `&#39;` is added. Due to I getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` error. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&#39` or `&amp;` are added by Rails when using '<%= ... %>' because it escapes HTML special characters. You can disabled this behavior with `raw` or `html_safe` :

```
var currency_list = [<%= raw currency_symbol_list %>];
var accounts_to_currency_list = [<%= raw accounts_to_currency_symbol_list(@child.pending_accounts) %>];
```

You can have a complete explanation here: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/